# Is It Possible To Handle Invalid References (SQL Server)?

Tags: sql-server, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I've very much enjoyed being able to shorten my code by using `reference` in my `Table` objects as well as `referencedOn` and `referrersOn` in my `Entitie`s. But as I've gotten further with my project, I've realized that I might have to undo all that work and recreate these processes manually in the event that the rows being referenced are deleted.

Is there any way of keeping these without risking `IllegalStateException`s (like being able to provide a default foreign key you know exists), or will I have to give it all up for manual reference methods?

Here is a minimal example:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    /* Connecting to DB here */
    transaction {
        val timesheets = TimeSheet.all()
        println("Printing time sheet list:")
        timesheets.forEach { sheet ->
            println("Time Sheet Object for employee ${sheet.employee}\n$sheet")
        }
    }
    /* Disconnecting to DB */
}

object EmployeeTable : IdTable<UUID>("employeeTable") {
    override val id = uuid("EmployeeUID").entityId().primaryKey()
}

object TimeSheetTable : IdTable<Int>("timeSheetTable") {
    override val id = integer("JobUID").primaryKey().autoIncrement().entityId()

    val employee = reference("EmployeeUID", EmployeeTable)
}

class Employee(id: EntityID<UUID>) : UUIDEntity(id) {
    companion object : UUIDEntityClass<Employee>(EmployeeTable)
}

class TimeSheet(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<TimeSheet>(TimeSheetTable)

    var employee by Employee referencedOn TimeSheetTable.employee
}
```

Once the list of time sheets tries to print a row where a Employee UID doesn't match any Employee rows, it'll throw:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find employeeTable WHERE id=some-invalid-id-string
```

Comment: Could you provide more details or sample code where you got `IllegalStateExceptions` ?

Comment: I've added a minimal example.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but how it's possible what your TimeSheet doesn't have a linked Employee while your reference is not optional?

If you expect what TimeSheet could be created without an employee then define it with optReference/optionalReferencedOn.

Comment: Does optional optReference/optionalReferencedOn help with invalid references? This is separate than having a NULL reference.

Comment: What is `invalid reference` ? If you have a foreign key you can only have a reference or not. Do you have tables without foreign keys?

Comment: Yes, the table does not have foreign keys. The database was managed before I came to work at my job. Apparently, the previous programmer did not link the tables and seemed to delete rows from the source table without cleaning up the other tables that held a reference. I can't just delete those rows though, they still hold important information for my company (like total hours worked in a project, necessary for charging customers). So is doing table joins my only option?

Comment: My advice is to: 
1. Make your reference column nullable in a database (if it's not so)
2. Set column value to null where ref.records are absent with SQL
3. Add foreign key constraint to a table.
4. Use optReference in Exposed.

Comment: Sounds good, thank you!